# Export matplotlib pdf with text not as path from tkinter

Tags: python, pdf, canvas, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a simple GUI that plots a figure like this:

```
def display_graph(self,f1):

     self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f1, self)
     self.canvas.show()
     self.canvas.get_tk_widget().place(anchor = N ,x = 200 ,y= 150)
     self.get_all_figures()
     self.canvas._tkcanvas.place(anchor = N ,x = 675 ,y= 325)
     self.toolbar_frame = Frame(self)
     toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas, self.toolbar_frame)
     self.toolbar_frame.place(anchor = N ,x = 540 ,y= 933)
```

There is some text like xlabel, ylabel and the user should be able to export in pdf format. To work with the figure it would be great if the displayed text was also a text object in for example Illustrator, but it is recognized just as a path. (no font information). 
I have changed the `pyl.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42` but it does only work when I plot directly from the console. 
Is there a trick to make it happen from a GUI using canvas?

To save the image I would like to use the toolbar and this function (depending on what the user clicks)

```
def save_all(figures,save_path_name,curr = 'all'):
 try:
      pp = PdfPages(save_path_name)

      if curr == 'last':

          pp.savefig(figures[-1])  

      else:
           for i in figures:
                pp.savefig(i)
      pp.close()
 except (OSError, IOError) as e:
          messagebox.showinfo('Error ...',e)
          return
```

Comment: You're missing the most important part in your code above, that is how do you save the image?

Comment: I would like to use the toolbar button that allows to save the image as a pdf

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest but indeed I have also writte a function that saves all generated figures , I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this does the trick. basically updating everytime before plotting any graph. But i was not able to make it work, even when i changed in the rc file. Very strange maybe I am overseeing something.

```
def display_graph(self,f1):
 plt.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42
 matplotlib.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42

 self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f1, self)
 self.canvas.show()
 self.canvas.get_tk_widget().place(anchor = N ,x = 200 ,y= 150)
 self.get_all_figures()
 self.canvas._tkcanvas.place(anchor = N ,x = 675 ,y= 325)
 self.toolbar_frame = Frame(self)
 toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas, self.toolbar_frame)
 self.toolbar_frame.place(anchor = N ,x = 540 ,y= 933)
```